# Sequence Convergence Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3+4n^2}{2n^2 - n } = 2$

We must use the definition of a convergent sequence: "A sequence $(s_n)$ is said to converge to the real number $s$ provided that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \leq n$ implies that $|s_n - s | < \epsilon$"

I am currently stuck on find a sequence s.t $\frac{3+4n^2}{2n^2 - n }  < f_n < \epsilon$.

How do you go about finding such a sequence? The upperbound of the numerator is..$n^2$? And the lower bound of the denominator is $\frac{1}{n}$?

So would $f_n = n^3$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @IanColey No. We must use the definition for a convergent sequence

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition is. Could you write it down?

Comment: @IanColey Edited accordingly.

Comment: Because you're dealing with a ratio, you need to keep your multiplicative constants. The numerator behaves like $4n^2$ for large $n$, and the denominator like $2n^2$; so the ratio behaves like $4n^2/2n^2= 2$ for large $n$. That's your limit. Now prove is rigorously since you know what the limit is.

Comment: Look at Did's answer. HOW does he make that latter inequality statement? Does he just make the RHS larger than the LHS ? Is there a process to it?

Comment: Simpler to ask this directly as a comment to Did's answer, no? Yes, amazingly, "there is a process to it"...

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{3+4n^2}{2n^2 - n }-2\right|=\frac{2n+3}{2n^2-n}=\frac1n\cdot\frac{2n+3}{2n-1}\leqslant\frac1n\cdot\frac{2n+3n}{2n-n}=\frac5n\to0$$

Comment: I'm...more used to the method LAcarguy used where we find another sequence to find our $n$. My confusion is in how we construct that sequence.

Comment: How do you make that latter inequality statement? Do you just make the sequence $f_n$ larger?

Comment: $n\geqslant1\implies2n+3\leqslant2n+3n\&2n-1\geqslant2n-n\implies\frac{2n+3n}{2n-1}\leqslant\ldots$

Comment: For the record, "the method LAcarguy used" and that you are "more used to" is EXACTLY the method used in my post. Hence I am not sure to understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  $(4n^2 + 3)/(2n^2 - n) - 2  = (2n + 3)/(2n^2 - n) < (2n + n)/n^2 < 3n/n^2 = 3/n$ when $n > 2$. So let epsilon $\epsilon > 0$ given, choose$ N = max{3/e, 2}$, then:
you have:  $f(n) - 2  < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$.

Comment: When you say $\frac{(2n+3)}{(2n^2 - n)} < \frac{3n}{n}$, how do do you make this statement? How do you know to write the numerator that way and the denominator that way. Also, why do you say when $n > 2$ ?

Comment: @ogodanalysis: think n is greater than any constant in your expression. so n > 3 ==> 2n + 3 < 3n. Second, n < n^2 ==> 2n^ - n > 2n^2 - n^2 = n^2.